# Monitor the size of the Azure Event Hub Partitions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have the Azure Event hub collecting events from multiple devices to multiple partitions.
Is there any way to monitor the size of the Azure Event hub partitions individually?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the partition depends on the MessageRetentionInDays setting for the entity and the TU allowance of the parent namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubdescription.messageretentionindays?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubDescription_MessageRetentionInDays